# Why is my term-mode-hook not selecting line mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wrote this elisp function:

```
(defun run (command)
  "Open a terminal running a command."
  (interactive "sCommand: ")
  (if (buffer-exists (concat "*" command "*" )) (kill-buffer (concat "*" command "*")))
  (let ((term-mode-hook (cons (lambda () (term-line-mode)) term-mode-hook)))
    (ansi-term (cons "sh" (cons "-i" (list "-c" command))) command)))
```

This works nicely except that the new ansi-term buffers remains in char mode (which is the default), so as far as I can tell the term-line-mode call is not doing anything. If I replace (term-line-mode) with (message "foo") I do see the message in the messages buffer.

The definition of term-line-mode in lisp/term.el is:

```
(defun term-line-mode  ()
  "Switch to line (\"cooked\") sub-mode of term mode.
This means that Emacs editing commands work as normally, until
you type \\[term-send-input] which sends the current line to the inferior."
  (interactive)
  (when (term-in-char-mode)
    (use-local-map term-old-mode-map)
    (term-update-mode-line)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to get "term-line-mode" to work as you want in any of the term hooks; however, it does work if you advise the "ansi-term" function:

```
(defadvice ansi-term (after advice-term-line-mode activate)
  (term-line-mode))
```