# A function that can toggle between term-char-mode and term-line-mode submodes?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In `term.el`, we can change from one submode to another. But, is there a way to toggle between them with one function (and one key-binding)?

Another question: Is there a way to mark text with keyboard in `term-char-mode`?

Answer (score 7):

First, one should ask a single question in a single SO posting.

Second, there is no toggle function in [`term.el`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html) but you can add one yourself:

```
(defun term-toggle-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (if (term-in-line-mode) 
      (term-char-mode)
      (term-line-mode)))
(define-key term-mode-map "\C-c\C-t" 'term-toggle-mode)
```

You can see other term keymaps using <kbd>C-h a term.*map RET</kbd> and add `define-key` forms for them too.

Third, use the [`cua`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html) library to select text with keyboard.

Comment: Thank you. Your function term-toggle-mode works. But, the key-binding only works in term-line-mode submode and not in the other one.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use `term`myself. You should add a `define-key` for all other maps that you want to have the toggle command available in.

Comment: The answer is explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816877/why-is-my-term-mode-hook-not-selecting-line-mode

Comment: For anyone ending up here, the solution is given [there](https://joelmccracken.github.io/entries/switching-between-term-mode-and-line-mode-in-emacs-term/). You have to add the same keybindings in ```term-raw-map``` : ```(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c C-t") 'term-toggle-mode)```. Maybe answer's OP can edit his almost perfect answer.